# Telegram Bot Live Location via node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

**How Can I send telegram bot live location?**

I'm using `node-telegram-bot-api` Module.

**Code:**
This Code just Send a Location

```
    await bot.sendLocation(msg.chat.id, 35.804819, 51.434070);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
bot.onText(/\/livelocation/, async  msg => {
    await bot.sendLocation(msg.chat.id, 35.804819, 51.434070, {
        live_period: 86400,
    });
});
```