# Sending Live Location to TelegramBot via Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

**How can I get users' live location when they share it with a Telegram Bot?**

I am using `node-telegram-bot-api` in this project. I have managed to get the bot request one-time location from the users. Here's the code:

```
import TelegramBot from 'node-telegram-bot-api';    
const token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

// Create a bot that uses 'polling' to fetch new updates
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.onText(/start/, (msg) => {
  const opts = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: [
        [{text: 'Location Request', request_location: true}],
      ],
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true,
    }),
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'some message goes here', opts);
});

bot.on('location', (msg) => {
  //console.log(msg.location.latitude);
  //console.log(msg.location.longitude);
  //do something with the lat long
)};
```

But I need the bot to capture live location from the users. There is a small reference to this question in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994056/telegram-bot-live-location-via-node-js) but that answer is for the bot sending its live location to the user. I need it to be the other way around.